# How to access a model in the site index file and layout in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have created a table which has site details as columns eg email address, phone number, site logo etc.

I have also created a site details model, but the problem is I can't figure out how to pass these models to my site index file or layout

This my sitecontroller code

```html
 public function actionIndex()
    {
   $model = new SiteDetails();
   // meta keywords
                 
        return $this->render('index',['model' => $model]);
  
  
    }
```

And this is how I am trying to access my model site address column in my site index file

```html
<div >
    <p> 
     <?= HtmlPurifier::process($model->address) ?>
    </p>
</div >
```

Comment: your code is fine. what seem to be your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to your view / layout by defining them in your controller:

```
$this->view->params['customParam'] = 'customValue';
```

Inside the view or the layout you can access this parameter by:

```
echo $this->params['customParam'];
```

This is also described in the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#sharing-data-among-views)